# Do friends' villagers retain their original furniture?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I was wondering, if a villager from my town (who I have given furniture to replace their original set) moves to a friend's town, will he retain the furniture I have given him or reset back to what he had when he first moved into my town?

Say, if Friga has royal furniture and my friend wants royal furniture, can my friend have Friga move to his town to get the furniture even if Friga's has been replaced?

Comment: As far as I know furniture is chosen at random, from specific themes for each villager, as soon as they move in. My guess would be the furniture they have now would be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! She will have all the things that she had while in your town upon moving to another. 
The only reason i know, is because Phoebe was in my friends town and when she moved away, she came to my town a few days later with all of the stuff from her other town. She even sings that towns tune to me. The only bad thing is her furniture was all mish mash :S